# how to automatically send a form when certain word is typed in a textbox-PHP?

Tags: php, form-submit

If the word ".xml" is typed the form will be sent without the need of pressing the submit button?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's not PHP matter. You need JavaScript/jQuery for that.

http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in JS or jQuery as Forien said.

Here is a jQuery solution to get you on the right tracks. Not sure if it works but have a play around:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#textf" ).keypress(function() {
        if($("#textf").contains(".xml")){
             $( "#testform" ).submit();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Yup, pretty much like that. Should work. I was too lazy for it :D You can also add info about need of including jQuery plugin so OP will know

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to do this in PHP, but you can use a keyup listener, like follows:

```js
$(document).on("keyup", "#watch", function() {
  // console.log($(this).val());
  if ($(this).val() === ".xml") {
    $('form#form-watch').submit();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form-watch">
  <input type="text" id="watch" />
</form>
```